# If someone is a Monotheistic ( like a agnostic) is he Muslims or will he go to heaven

Tags: allah, conversion

I know a Pearson who is a agnostic and is a physical science at my high school. I know Arabic, Islamic law(Figh) the life of the companions of the Prophet Muhammad(SalaaAllahu alahi wa salam)( or SAW) so can agnostic person be Muslim? He believes that god can be one or many. He just doesn’t know, he is just ignorant. He is a really religious person and remind of the father sa’ad ibm zaid. Zayd bin Amr Was a monotheistic and died in 605. I’m not comparing hem this teacher but he told me that he will not become a  Muslim until he looks into all religions.

Answer (score 1):

If someone does not believe in:

1. Allah alone (1 god)
2. Prophet Muhammad (25 prophets)
3. The Holy Scriptures
4. The day of judgement
5. The angels
6. Jesus being only a messenger and prophet of God

If someone does not:

1. Follow the Qur’an
2. Believe in the Qur’an
3. Identify as Muslim
4. (Essentially following the 5 pillars)

They will be going to hell.

> “Indeed, the religion in the sight of Allah is Islām. And those who were given the Scripture did not differ except after knowledge had come to them - out of jealous animosity between themselves. And whoever disbelieves in the verses of Allah, then indeed, Allah is swift in [taking] account.” 
> —Qur’an 3:19